# Print the number of digits before a decimal point

Tags: java, eclipse

I know there are ways to get the number of digits after a decimal point, for instance the substring method, but how would I go about doing this for the number of digits before a decimal place?

I need to use this to convert US change (double) into Euro change(double). The way I would like to do this is by taking the number before a decimal (such as $1.)  and times it by its euro equivalent (.7498) and take the number after a decimal (.16) and times that by its .01 euro coin value (.0075), add both values together to get the euro equivalent of $1.16 (.8698).

Comment: What? Why don't you just multiply it as a floating point number (i.e. a `double`)? `1.16 * 0.7468` will give you the correct answer...

Comment: I'm not convinced downvoting is meant to be used for questions where the OP has just got the wrong idea of how to do something - it will serve as a useful signpost for future peope if the correct method is highlighted - upvoting for that reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the number before decimal point,do this:

```
String str = new Double(your_double_number).toString().subString(0,str.indexOf('.'));
double v = Double.valueOf(str);
```

If you are using '$' sign then take 1 in place of 0.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

> convert US change (double) into Euro change(double)

Please don't do that. [Never, never, ever](http://blog.devspan.com/2007/06/working-with-money-using-floating-point.html) use `double` or `float` to represent money, because those datatypes [cannot represent most decimal fractions](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/), so you get rounding errors before you even start to do any calculations.

Instead, use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - just multiplying the Dollar value by the exchange rate will get you the euro value so there's no need to do that as far as i can see - you will just introduce rounding errors.

But if you did need to - just use substring

```
String dollarVal = "$1.16"
String justFullDollar = dollarVal.substring(1, dollarVal.indexOf("."));
String justCents = dollarVal.substring(dollarVal.indexOf(".")+1);
```

The Correct way would be to store all you money as integers or arbitrary precision objects that way you get no floating point errors too.

Convert to cents, multiply and convert back again.
e.g.

```
String dollarVal = "$1.16"
BigDecimal dollars = new BigDecimal(dollarVal.substring(1)); //1.16
BigDecimal cents = dollars.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)); //116
BigDecimal eurocents = cents.multiply(new BigDecimal(exchangeRate)); //86.9768
BigDecimal euros = eurocents.divide(new BigDecimal(100)); //0.869768
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.00");
String euroVal = "€" + formatter.format(euros);
```

Comment: THanks for that - was being an idiot for no good reason - fixed my example avoiding floating point and rounding errors

Comment: Okay thankyou Matt. I'll study this and reply back with another other concerns I have.

Comment: ^^ When I run my program, using your method, instead of printing ".869768" like yours does, it prints. ".00869768"(...etc.)

Comment: What exchange rate are you using to multiply by?

Comment: I was using .0075. I've figured out that I have to use .7528 ($1.00) to get the correct answer.

Comment: Also, Multiplying numbers such as: $.16, 1.16,11.16 and 111.16, by .7528 are all  the right value in euros, but from xxxx.xx and onwards I'll have to use the $100 exchange rate(75.2751) and divide by 10000 in order to get the correct value.

Comment: No - you don't have different exchange rates for different parts.  There is just 1 exchange rate - the exchange rate from dollars to euros.  You are just decreasing precision by using different rates for different magnitudes.  1 U.S. dollar = 0.753579503 Euros currently - so just use a BigDecimal of that value (changing as frequently as you see fit) for all magnitudes.  By rounding that value to 0.7536 (For $1.00) and 0.753580 (For $100.00) you'll introduce rounding errors.

Comment: Okay. My values seem to be coming out correctly this time. I had my exchange Rate as a double instead of a big decimal. So in general, when doing calculations with money, should all numerical values be declared as a Big Decimal?

Comment: I guess it depends on the situation - I tend to store everything as integers (pence, cents, eurocents etc) as i don't ever deal with values high enough to require it - and don't have to deal with string conversions.  If you need to convert from strings or use numbers big enough to justify it BigDecimal is the way to go - The important point is not to use floating point representations as you will loose precision, here's a nice article worth a read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29637/Five-Tips-for-Floating-Point-Programming

Comment: Also: Here is a quick code example of why floats are not precise.

http://ideone.com/kgdiS

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String s[] = new Double(your number).toString().split(".");
```

The **s[0]** is the number before decimal point. and **s[1]** is the number after decimal point.

Both are in String, so you need to parse them into double using

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(s[0]);
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(s[1]);
```